# Function that uniformly converges to 0, but doesn't converges to 0 in norm.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral, banach-spaces

Is there any sequence of function ${f_n}$ that fulfill 3 condition?

1. Each function ${f_n} \in L^2(0, \infty)$, for every $n$.
2. ${f_n}$ converges uniformly to 0 that is: for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > N \Rightarrow |f_n(x)| < \epsilon$
3. ${f_n}$ doesn't converges in norm $L^2(0, \infty)$. Norm in $L^2(0, \infty)$ is defined by $$\Vert f \Vert ^2 = \int_{0}^{\infty} |f(x)|^2 dx$$

Basically, the question is: sequence of function $f_n$ that converges uniformly to 0 but doesn't converges in norm to 0.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1{\sqrt n}&\text{ if }x\leqslant n\\0&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$and use the fact that $(\forall n\in\Bbb N):\|f\|_2=1$.

Comment: I got it now. Thx in advanced.

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: Yes. I have given a mark.

Comment: If you have upvoted my answer, thank you. But I wrote about *accepting* it, which means to click on the ✓ sign.